# Составление регулярного выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такая строка

```
$cond($eq($HND,1),0.85*($m1*1.2*1.03*$MWS/100)+0.03*($MW+$mw)/2-1,1.2*($m1*1.2*1.03*$MWS/100)+0.03*($MW+$mw)/2+1)
```

Ее нужно разложить на составляющие функции

```
$cond($eq($HND,1),0.85*($m1*1.2*1.03*$MWS/100)+0.03*($MW+$mw)/2-1,1.2*($m1*1.2*1.03*$MWS/100)+0.03*($MW+$mw)/2+1) // функция
$eq($HND,1)
0.85*($m1*1.2*1.03*$MWS/100)+0.03*($MW+$mw)/2-1,1.2*($m1*1.2*1.03*$MWS/100)+0.03*($MW+$mw)/2+1
```

И все остальные функции, лежащие в ней, нужно так же разложить

```
$eq($HND,1) //функция
$HND
1
```

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Пытался подставлять специфические выражения, но они обрывались на первых запятых/закрывающих скобках/етц.

Comment: В текущем виде, вопрос сводится к "_сделайте за меня_", а такие вопросы тут не очень-то любят

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я понимаю, но увы не знаю как сделать так, что бы оно парсило до последней закрывающей скобки и контент внутри разделялся через запятые на аргументы

Comment: Надо брать и писать парсер.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно ограничиться простой рекуррентной функцией, разбивающей строку на имя "функции" и "аргументы" ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy я собственно его и делаю, только хочу максимально упростить его с помощью regex

Comment: @DmitriySimushev А можно поподробнее про такую функцию?

Comment: А вот не надо тут regex. Надо нормально писать.

Comment: Эм... берете и парсите внешнее выражение. Получаете имя функции и аргументы, затем рекуррентно прасите каждый из аргументов. Повторяете до тех пор, пока можно парсить. Если вы ждете от меня готовый код, то я его писать не буду))

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать Regexp, то можно так:

1. Ищем функцию с помощью Regexp `(\$\w+)\(\s*((?:[^,()]|(\((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?3))*\)))+(?:\s*,\s*(?:[^,()]|(\((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?3))*\)))+)*)\s*\)`. В первой группе захвата будет имя функции, во второй - аргументы.
2. В цикле получаем массив аргументов, применяя Regexp `\s*((?:[^,()]|(\((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?2))*\)))+)\s*(?:,|$)` к строке с аргументами из п.1 (отдельный аргумент будет в первой группе захвата).
3. К каждому найденному аргументу применяем п.1 и т.д. пока не дойдем до конца.

При этом есть ограничения/особенности [PHP: Рекурсивные шаблоны](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

Но вообще, такой разбор делается с помощью парсеров. Посмотрите [php-peg](https://github.com/hafriedlander/php-peg). Там надо будет составить простенькую грамматику для выражения вызова функции, и скорее всего его можно найти в грамматике PHP.